# Reverse engineer open source project looking for methods

Tags: open-source, reverse-engineering, sequence-diagram

i have open source project done in c++ , it is big and has no documentation
now to "only" to debug it and understand its flow it is possible but very hard.
im looking for well define methods and ways of work , to make this process easier.
like some kind of tools that can help me to draw the objects and class's relationship.
**UPDATE**
well after digging some more , i know the proper name for this is :
Sequence Diagrams , so i looking how to get Sequence Diagrams out of c++ code
it have to be free tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here you can find your answer, System Sequence Diagram maybe helps you. if answer not enough tell me to say more details :)

http://www.devcurry.com/2010/03/generate-sequence-diagrams-in-visual.html

and also this link is useful too:

http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/11/20/visual-studio-2010-generating-sequence-diagrams-on-the-fly.aspx

Comment: Thanks but i dont have the full 2010 vc , im using the express version and this option is missing there . 
i need some free option

Answer (score 0):

[Understand for C++](http://www.scitools.com/) from Scientific Toolworks has a good reputation.  I have no specific experience with it.

Comment: looks very good but its not free